# Chinese Keyboard returned different keycode when pressing F1

Tags: keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys, input-devices, xev

Since I don't have much data, I'll just keep this in short.

So I bought a mechanical keyboard. Everytime I press F1 the window defocuses. F2 works.

Pressing F1 in `xev`:

```
FocusOut event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    mode NotifyWhileGrabbed, detail NotifyNonlinear

FocusIn event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    mode NotifyWhileGrabbed, detail NotifyNonlinear

KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusIn event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Pressing F2 in `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0x290, subw 0x0, time 45947409, (234,268), root:(235,302),
    state 0x0, keycode 68 (keysym 0xffbf, F2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
   XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0x290, subw 0x0, time 45947546, (234,268), root:(235,302),
    state 0x0, keycode 68 (keysym 0xffbf, F2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So pretty much `xev` can't recognize the F1 key, but F2 can. Note that if I press + it recognizes this as `keycode 179 (keysym 0x1008ff81, XF86Tools)`. So maybe there's a way to bind `XF86Tools` to `F1`? I'm running Openbox. Checked `dconf-editor` for keybindings but nothing there. Thank you.

**Edit1**: So I tried binding F1 to something in Openbox. F1 alone doesn't work, W-F1 works though. If I open Keyboard Settings in XFCE, F1 registers but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

Okay, so after a while messing in `xkeycaps`, I decided to try out different keyboard layouts, the 104 keys and the 105 keys. Looking that the layout, I found out that in the 104 keys layout, the F1 key was bound to 43. The 105 keys on the other hand, bound the F1 key to "Help". This means by changing the keyboard layout from 105 keys to 104, I could solve this problem.

1. Edit `/etc/default/keyboard`. Inside you'll find the line

> `XKBMODEL="pc105"`

Change `pc105` to `pc104`

2. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`

And the F1 key can now be detected using `xev`